# How would I use .get() in my function to only grab what's in the dictionary?

Tags: python, exception, get

I have my function here:

```
def DBCount(self, db_count_dict):
    schema= self.config["data-validation"]["database"]["schema"]
    unique_cols= self.config["data-validation"]["RULES"]["RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]["UNIQUE_TABLES"][self.table].split(",")
    db_count_dict[self.table]={}

    for i in range(len(unique_cols)):
        try:
            cnxn=None
            cnxn = SourceValidation.getDBConnection(self.env)
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            print("UNIQUE COL: "+str(unique_cols[i]))
            unique_count_query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "+unique_cols[i]+") as unique_count FROM "+schema+"."+self.table
            df = pd.read_sql(unique_count_query, cnxn)
            db_count_dict[self.table][unique_cols[i]]=str(df['unique_count'].values[0])

        except KeyError:
            pass

    return db_count_dict
```

I tried using the exception but it's not working. I think only grabbing what I have in listed in the dictionary would be a better way to do this. The code grabs the columns I listed in a separate config file, it errors out when I try to grab a table that's not listed.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you, you want to handle the case where your config does not have a particular key in it for the current `self.table`

Rather than:

```
unique_cols= self.config["data-validation"]["RULES"]["RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]["UNIQUE_TABLES"][table_name].split(",")
```

Try:

```
unique_cols= self.config["data-validation"]["RULES"]["RULE_UNIQUE_VALIDATION"]["UNIQUE_TABLES"].get(table_name)
if not unique_cols:
    return {}

unique_cols = unique_cols.split(",")
```